# How to get "GET" request parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to get "GET" variables from request in JavaScript?

Does jQuery or YUI! have this feature built-in?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

**Update June 2021:**

Today's browsers have built-in APIs for working with URLs ([URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)) and query strings ([URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) and these should be preferred, unless you need to support some old browsers or Opera mini ([Browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=URLSearchParams)).

**Original:**

All data is available under

```
window.location.search
```

you have to parse the string, eg.

```
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
```

just call the function with GET variable name as parameter, eg.

```
get('foo');
```

this function will return the variables value or undefined if variable has no value or doesn't exist

Comment: @Daniel Silveira: yes, it could/should decode the value (and encode the name). Will edit my post in few moments

Comment: Note that decodeURIComponent does not decode /all/ possible URI escapes. In particular "+" won't be decoded as " ". (I forget which browser this was in. FF, maybe?) The spec requires them to only decode exactly what encodeUIRComponent encodes, and it will encode " " as "%20", so "+" is left alone.

Comment: This is why I like PHP

Comment: @volocuga unlike PHP, dealing with URLs in JavaScript is quite rare operation, so browser vendors never really focused on these features.

Comment: brilliantly answered Rafael ;)

Comment: @andrewdotn yes, I totally agree. I've added info about outdated solution and linked the URLSearchParams.

Answer (score 36):

You could use `jquery.url` I did like this:

```
var xyz = jQuery.url.param("param_in_url");
```

[Check the source code](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser/blob/master/jquery.url.js)

Updated Source: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Comment: Great answer, but your link is dead

Comment: @Adam it would appear so.  I think this is the updated URL: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser A google search on Mark Perkins jquery.url led me to an update.  I have the source from when I posted this answer if you need it.

Comment: So a plugin is required?

Comment: `var xyz = jQuery.url().param("param_in_url");` is the correct syntax where `jQuery.url()` gives the the current page URL. Please make the correction.

Answer (score 22):

try the below code, it will help you get the GET parameters from url .
[for more details.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams)

```
 var url_string = window.location.href; // www.test.com?filename=test
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var paramValue = url.searchParams.get("filename");
    alert(paramValue)
```

Comment: not works in example http://localhost:8080/#/?access_token=111 because of location.hash part. If '#' symbol occurs location.search is empty

Comment: url with "#" symbol is not supported so we have to remove that.
try this : 


var url_string = window.location.href; // www.test.com?filename=test
    var url = new URL(url_string.replace("#/",""));
    var paramValue = url.searchParams.get("access_token");
    alert(paramValue)

Comment: NOT supported in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 12):

Just to put my two cents in, if you wanted an object containing all the requests

```
function getRequests() {
    var s1 = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length).split('&'),
        r = {}, s2, i;
    for (i = 0; i < s1.length; i += 1) {
        s2 = s1[i].split('=');
        r[decodeURIComponent(s2[0]).toLowerCase()] = decodeURIComponent(s2[1]);
    }
    return r;
};

var QueryString = getRequests();

//if url === "index.html?test1=t1&test2=t2&test3=t3"
console.log(QueryString["test1"]); //logs t1
console.log(QueryString["test2"]); //logs t2
console.log(QueryString["test3"]); //logs t3
```

Note, the key for each get param is set to lower case. So, I made a helper function. So now it's case-insensitive.

```
function Request(name){
    return QueryString[name.toLowerCase()];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Unlike other answers, the [`UrlSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object can avoid using Regexes or other string manipulation and is available is most modern browsers:

```
var queryString = location.search
let params = new URLSearchParams(queryString)
// example of retrieving 'id' parameter
let id = parseInt(params.get("id"))
console.log(id)
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to differentiate this answer a bit more from others?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the URL to acquire the GET variables.  In particular, `window.location.search` gives everything after (and including) the '?'.  You can read more about window.location [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location).

Answer (score 3):

A map-reduce solution:

```
var urlParams = location.search.split(/[?&]/).slice(1).map(function(paramPair) {
        return paramPair.split(/=(.+)?/).slice(0, 2);
    }).reduce(function (obj, pairArray) {            
        obj[pairArray[0]] = pairArray[1];
        return obj;
    }, {});
```

Usage:

```
For url: http://example.com?one=1&two=2
console.log(urlParams.one) // 1
console.log(urlParams.two) // 2
```

Comment: Could you please address why would you use a map-reduce solution for this? As far as I understand, map-reduce is efficient when handling really big datasets. As this is just an HTTP request, I don't see the point of using a map-reduce solution.

Comment: actually `map/reduce` is just a collections processing mechanism: can be used with any size data. it is more famous for big data due to its willingness to be parallelized

Answer (score 2):

Today I needed to get the page's request parameters into a associative array so I put together the following, with a little [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520845) from [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503) [friends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520845). It also handles parameters without an `=` as `true`.

With an example:

```
// URL: http://www.example.com/test.php?abc=123&def&xyz=&something%20else

var _GET = (function() {
    var _get = {};
    var re = /[?&]([^=&]+)(=?)([^&]*)/g;
    while (m = re.exec(location.search))
        _get[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = (m[2] == '=' ? decodeURIComponent(m[3]) : true);
    return _get;
})();

console.log(_GET);
> Object {abc: "123", def: true, xyz: "", something else: true}
console.log(_GET['something else']);
> true
console.log(_GET.abc);
> 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the URL of the current page to obtain the GET parameters. The URL can be found by using `location.href`.

Comment: Note that this isn't entirely reliable, as the server may have redirected you elsewhere.  But it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you already use jquery there is a jquery plugin that handles this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

Answer (score 0):

The function here returns the parameter by name. With tiny changes you will be able to return base url, parameter or anchor.

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    var urlOld          = window.location.href.split('?');
    urlOld[1]           = urlOld[1] || '';
    var urlBase         = urlOld[0];
    var urlQuery        = urlOld[1].split('#');
    urlQuery[1]         = urlQuery[1] || '';
    var parametersString = urlQuery[0].split('&');
    if (parametersString.length === 1 && parametersString[0] === '') {
        parametersString = [];
    }
    // console.log(parametersString);
    var anchor          = urlQuery[1] || '';

    var urlParameters = {};
    jQuery.each(parametersString, function (idx, parameterString) {
        paramName   = parameterString.split('=')[0];
        paramValue  = parameterString.split('=')[1];
        urlParameters[paramName] = paramValue;
    });
    return urlParameters[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in

url: http://localhost:8080/#/?access_token=111

```
function get(name){
  const parts = window.location.href.split('?');
  if (parts.length > 1) {
    name = encodeURIComponent(name);
    const params = parts[1].split('&');
    const found = params.filter(el => (el.split('=')[0] === name) && el);
    if (found.length) return decodeURIComponent(found[0].split('=')[1]);
  }
}
```