# Use Javascript to reload the page and specify a jquery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to use javascript to reload a page.  I can't just use
`window.location.reload();` as I'm using jquery tabs and want to specify a tab to be selected after the reload. Is setting `window.location.href` the best way to do this?

i.e. `window.location.href = window.location.href + '#tabs-4';`

Comment: have you tried window.location.hash='#tabs-4' ?

Comment: @amosrivera I assume that will not reload the page though?

Comment: you can load content for that specific tab by using: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-load would that work?

Comment: If you want to load the whole page again, than your method is probably best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brandon Joyce commented, my original code was probably best:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '#tabs-4';
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way:

```
window.location.hash = 'tabs-4';
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to pass a var in the url (post) than with your javascript retreive it and select the tab associated to the var

Answer (score 0):

you can have variable in redirect link like 
index.html?tab=4
and than check it's value in javascript.

```
function get(name){
```

if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
you can use this code to get a value. like

```
selec=get('tab');
 $tabs.tabs('select', selec);
```

to switch to a tab. 
See this link to get more details about

[How to get "GET" request parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-variables-from-request-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to reload the page from within a function if certain conditions are met.  I can't just use a link.

Comment: but you can generate link on the basic of your condition. 
if(condition 1 ){
when you want to redirect page and switch to tab 1
link=link+"?tab=1"
}