# How can I pass values from one html page to another html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In first page im getting value in textbox i need to pass it to another page which is divided into 2 frames.
I need to display that value in first frame's html page.
Please provide me a simple example.
I tried with
window.document.getElementById("inputbox1").value
but im unable to get the value.

Please provide me a simple example.

Answer (score 9):

I would go with localStorage, as @MicrosoftGoogle propose, but is not well supported yet, you can use pure javascript to achieve this. You will have something like this on your form page:

```
<form action="param-received.html" method="GET">
   <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Once you click on Send button,you will be redirect to `/param-received.html?foo=hola&submit=Send`.

- `location.search` attribute contains the chain of parameters.
- ?   concatenates the URL and the string of parameters.
- &   separates multiple parameters.
- =   assigns a value to the variable.

Here is the complete code to process data sent on `param-received.html`:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function processForm()
  {
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    l = unescape(temp[1]);
    alert(l); //Dialog with the text you put on the textbox
  }
  processForm();
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript?lq=1

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write the value in a cookie and read the cookie from the other page.

For writing and reading cookies check [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

if url parameters are an option you could use this

```
function getParameter(param) {
                var val = document.URL;
                var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
                var n=parseInt(url.replace(param+"=",""));
                alert(n+1); 
}
getParameter("page");
```

ref
http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-get-url-parameter-in-javascript.html

another might be cookies

---

was beaten to the cookie part :p

edit indeed not a good cookie reference
this one is better http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Have you read it the htmlgoodies article? Use the same function twice for the same thing, does not unescape parameters and does not even speak of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GET part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript) of the request or [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue(varname)
                {
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    var qparts = url.split("?");

                    if (qparts.length == 1)
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                    else{
                        var query = qparts[1];
                        var vars = query.split("&");
                        var value = "";
                        for (i=0;i<vars.length;i++)
                        {
                            var parts = vars[i].split("=");
                            if (parts[0] == varname)
                            {
                                value = parts[1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        value = unescape(value);

                        // Convert "+"s to " "s
                        value.replace(/\+/g," ");
                        return value;
                    }

                }
var VariableGot = getValue(YourPassingVariableName);
```

Just copy the function into your html file and pass your variable name to the function which is send through GET Method.Now You will get the value of the variable from url.