# how can i assign the html of a DOM element to my global variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable "theClass" that I try to assign the contents of a DOM element after a click event has occurred, then I try to use it on another page, but it's not even being assigned in the first place! This' the code, that returns ' false' in the console. I'm using jQuery.

```
var theClass = '';
var getCategories = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("click", ".nav li a", function() {
    theClass = $(this).html();
    getCategories = true;
  });

  console.log(theClass+" "+getCategories);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "another page"? if after the click you loaded a completely new page then all of your variables were erased.

Comment: It is a page level variable. Even when you refresh this goes off. You cannot transfer to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your code, I am assuming by another page you actually mean another place in your code. Your console log gets fired in the `ready` function, however, you are setting/updating the values in a function. Hence, your logging will not show result as expected.

You can try logging in the event based function only. And will see that the first log gives default values and then subsequent clicks give updated values.

You can try something like following

```
 $(document).on("click", ".nav li a", function() {
console.log(theClass+" "+getCategories);
theClass = $(this).html();
getCategories = true;

});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, just saw a post talking about 'localStorage' and that seems to work pretty well! Thanks though!

Comment: @VincentHokie - Good your problem got resolved, however, I would suggest you to understand the concepts as well.

Comment: from your answer, I seem to understand that the reason the updating and logging values are unchanged is because they're inside the 'ready' function..true?

Comment: @VincentHokie - In your case, yes, however, it is not necessary. The simple problem is that you are accessing before updating.

Comment: Ohhhhhh! Because, the logging is fired immediately the ready function is complete! Before which, there are no values..

Comment: I get that. But, I had multiple links, and I had a scenario where I set them from one click, (got nothing on the log ofcourse) but when I clicked a second link(at this point the variable should be set to the value of the first link) it still gave me undefined..

Comment: @VincentHokie - Does clicking on anchor reloads the page or take you to some other page, if yes, then it will give undefined only.

Comment: Takes you to another page. So would you say localStorage is the best solution now?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to set any value in global variable then it is valid in particular session,when I try to use it on another page then variable got initialize with global value as false.

Prefer below post for finding a another way.

[How can I pass values from one html page to another html page using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470285/how-can-i-pass-values-from-one-html-page-to-another-html-page-using-javascript)