# Check if value from function returned is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question (or similar) seems to get asked often, but I've tried many ways to check if the value returned from a function I have, is null or not; to no avail.

My function, get's URL parameters by name:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

However, obviously a parameter may not be there, so I need to do a check on the value returned.

Doing `console.log( getURLParameter('client') );` returns `null`...but doing null checks does not work.

I have tried the following:

```
if ( getURLParameter("client") !== null ) {

    alert("It's there matey!");

}

if ( getURLParameter("client") != null ) {

    alert("It's there matey!");

}

if ( ! getURLParameter("client") ) {

    alert("It's there matey!");

}
```

None of these seems to work for me.

Is there anywhere I am going wrong? I can do this either in vanilla JS, or using jQuery library.

Comment: Trust me, there's a better function to get a URL parameter (I know this function is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript ). You shouldn't need to run a regex every time you call the function.

Comment: All that was required to figure this out was straight-forward debugging. Break the statement up in to its individual parts and walk through the code with the debugger built into your browser. Doing so will be *dramatically* faster than typing in a question on SO.

Comment: I would suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values but not necessarily liking the accepted answer. (I prefer the second highest voted question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the value your function is returning is a string (`'null'`) and therefore it fails with your tests.

```
var result = getURLParameter("client");
console.log('Value: ' + result);                // 'null'
console.log('Data type: ' + typeof(result));    // string
console.log(result!==null);                     // true
console.log(result!=null);                      // true
console.log(!result);                           // false
```

It returns a string because you are passing the `null` value as parameter to the `decodeURI` function, which converts to the string `'null'`.

So, I edited your function `getURLParameter` to check if the value of the param is `null` **before** calling `decodeURI`. See below:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    var param = RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || null;
    return param===null ? null : decodeURI(param[1]);
}
```

Now, let's run the tests again:

```
var result = getURLParameter("client");
console.log('Value: ' + result);                // null
console.log('Data type: ' + typeof(result));    // object
console.log(result!==null);                     // false
console.log(result!=null);                      // false
console.log(!result);                           // true
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is `decodeURI`, which is returning the **string** `"null"` when you pass `null` into it. The solution is to do the `null` check before calling `decodeURI`. You can find this by just breaking the function up into its parts:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    var rex = RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)');
    var result = rex.exec(location.search);
    var rv = decodeURI(
      (result||[,null])[1]
    );
    return rv;
}
```

...and walking through it in the debugger built into your browser.

Or for those who prefer `console.log`-style debugging:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    var rex = RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)');
    var result = rex.exec(location.search);
    console.log("typeof result = " + typeof result);
    console.log("result = " + result);
    var rv = decodeURI(
      (result||[,null])[1]
    );
    console.log("typeof rv = " + typeof rv);
    return rv;
}
```

...which for `getURLParameter("foo")` shows us:

```
typeof result = object
result = null
typeof rv = string
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if ( getURLParameter("client") != 'null' ) {

    alert("It's there matey!");

}
```

Comment: And what if the value **actually is** "null"?

Comment: isn't the `!=` operator casting the expressions? so "null" and 'null' is no difference.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I'm saying what if the querystring is this: `?p1=null`? If you used `getURLParameter("p1")`, the result would be `"null"`, and your solution would fail to see it

Comment: ...and even if it weren't for @Ian's very good point, that test doesn't work anyway: `null != 'null'` returns `true`.