# How to access request query string parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I've seen numerous solutions that utilize RegEx, and to be quite frank, that seems ridiculously excessive since javascript is so versatile.

There must be a simpler way to access request parameters.

Could somebody demonstrate for me?

Comment: Did you try to produce some code on your own?

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Comment: I believe OP refers to the query string attached to the URL of the current page. Clarifying that _might_ help, but really it seems clear enough to me.

Comment: See also [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a useful method in the [depths of the net](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/07/accessing-querystring-through-java.html).

```
function querySt(Key) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    KeysValues = url.split(/[\?&]+/);
    for (i = 0; i < KeysValues.length; i++) {
        KeyValue = KeysValues[i].split("=");
        if (KeyValue[0] == Key) {
            return KeyValue[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Downvotes and plugins aside, thanks anyways.

Comment: nice work finding a raw javascript version, however, that's not what you asked for.

Comment: I actually like the pure javascript version, as it doesn't require loading in some additional library. Either way, glad you came up with a solution.

Comment: Minor point of contention: your `.split()` uses a RegEx, which you complained about in the question. Not that I'd do it differently. =)

Comment: This works in my case but I notice this doesn't handle arrays - what if there are multiple values for one parameter (i.e. param1=val1&param1=val2&param1=val3)? Neat solution which works for most situations in any case.

Comment: `window.location.search`, I suppose. (For reasons seen e.g. [here, in probably the best guide on URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding).)

Comment: forgot to `return "";` or null at the end of the function in case key is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery plugin  [Purl (A JavaScript URL parser) v2.3.1](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

```
var queryStringParameter = $.url().param('queryStringParameter');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery BBQ plugin to the rescue.   See [deparam method](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/)