# How can javascript return a query parameter to client

Tags: javascript, web-services, query-string

Can javascript act like a web service and return a parameter value received in a query string to the client that posted the query?  I am trying to return a query parameter in C# with no success.  For example, if the query string is http://www.mypage/service?hubchallenge=1234 what javascript code would be used to return the value 1234 to the client without returning the web page itself?

Comment: you need to look at AJAX for how to do it.. I'm not a C# guy so don't know about implementation

Comment: See the solutions in [here][1] and [here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript

Comment: I believe the suggestions will return a value from a function.  However, I want to return the value to a client that posted the query.  Can that be done in javascript?

Comment: By returning a value using these suggestions, the whole html page is returned after pageload.  I don't want to return the page, just the value.  Can that be done?

Comment: Basically I want to do an echo like in PHP only do it in javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should have to you AJAX for it in your page. It cannot be done without passing a request from the client.
The below javascript code has to be placed in the page which send request.

```
function test()//the function can be called on events
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for other browsers
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET"," http://www.mypage/service?hubchallenge=1234",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can get the url into a string like this:

```
var urlString=document.URL;
```

then you can parse out parameters like

```
var qs=urlString.split("?")[1];
var qsArray=qs.split("&");
```