# trasferring the Array created in the html page to another page

Tags: html, arrays, web, copy

I need help to transfer an array from one page to another page. Following is the code that I created with a list of names.
In another papge, I want to this array and also print them out. I am wondering whether I could get this array by javascript. Thank you so much!
I have seperated two paragrahs of code so that you can easily read them. Thanks a lot!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ys</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var aName = new Array;
aName[0] = "daniel";
aName[1] = "zhang";
aName[2] = "alex";
aName[3] = "yang";
aName[4] = "Amy";
aName[5] = "Wang";
aName[6] = "Vincent";
aName[7] = "Lee";

for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
document.write(aName[i] + "<br>")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>get the array from s.html and print out</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


for (i=0; i<8; i++)
{
document.write(aName[i] + "<br>")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external js file if your array is hard-coded.

**somefile.js**

```
var aName = ["daniel","zhang", "alex", "yang", "Amy", "Wang", "Vincent", "Lee"];
```

**Html**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javscript" src="somefile.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          for (i = 0; i < aName.length; i++)
          {
             document.write(aName[i] + "<br>")
          }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Other ways: If you use modern browser you can user [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) for storing big string and split it every time by divider.
Or using cookies but it's ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, life-cycle management. Is it OK to send it as a parameter? For example,

https://www.google.com/search?q=weather

If yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146311/227646 which says

> Encode the array as a request parameter.
>
> You should turn your array into a URI encoded string, so probably passing through something like JSON first.
>
> Then decode the parameter in the www.testpage.faces.html
>
> [How to get "GET" request parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-variables-from-request-in-javascript)

If no (sensitive information), we will have to store it in the browser somehow. Perhaps a cookie?