# How do i retrieve this information using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to retrieve the information between “tmad=” and “&tmpageid” using javascript.

example: www.url.com/tmad1234&tmpageid88

Comment: You can find the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: If you are wondering why you are getting downvotes, try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean www.url.com/tmad=1234&tmpageid88 the following should do the trick

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}

getQueryVariable("tmad");
```