# Passing URL parameters to sendy form

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, parameter-passing, sendy

I want to pass a parameter into the field "name" of my Sendy form. I want to write in the URL like www.mywebsite.com/**?src=works** and "works" appear as the name of the subscriber. But how can I implement this? I already tried with "GET", but with no success. Thanks.

```
<form action="http://trackingit.in/subscribe" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name">&nbsp;<label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email">&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="list" value="(hidden)">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>&nbsp;
```

Comment: you tagged as php, but no code to support the question

Comment: Yes Sorry. Deleted php.

Comment: the reason may be in your php. You should probably post that and then add the php tag back in again. Or do you not have any php?

Comment: Im using Optimizepress (wordpress plugin) where I have a field to insert a html form. The form works OK, but i want to pass a parameter to save as a "name". Maybe its wordpress problem ?

Comment: If getting request parameter from php request is not an option, you can use javascript and here is how [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript). Then use javascript (any framework jquery, angualr,....) to set the request param value to name.

Comment: form action is ```http://trackingit.in/subscribe``` and method is ```POST``` input text name ```NAME``` and you wanted to get ```http://www.mywebsite.com/?src=works``` I'm quite confuse, maybe post a clear code that you actually used and the parameter you wanted to get and what happened when you click submit assuming you set the method to ```GET```,

Comment: I want to put the "Works" from the URL into the field "name" in the form. Is just that. dont need more code =/