# Read POST query string from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, post

Given following page test.html doing a form submit to another page post.html:

```
    <form action="post.html" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="qwerty"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Is it possible using JavaScript or jQuery in post.html to read value of t1.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Based on your example code, it's hard to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: Edited question, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read the post request parameters using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409013/how-to-read-the-post-request-parameters-using-javascript)

Comment: This do not seem to be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value in an input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Server** side handles **POST** data.

And **javascript** is **client** side. so, it is not possible by javascript

Comment: But if the form uses method GET instead it is possible. Why not with POST :(

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: I know it is possible to do using GET, but I'm locked to handle POST.

Comment: How can you handle a server side post request using a client side program?