# Passing parameter jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a template to a given DIV in my main .html file. I am trying to use jquery:

```
$('#Selected').load("template.html",{REQUIREDID:PARENTID})
```

The template loads correctly but I am unable to pass the variable and use it in the template. For example `<div>"requiredid"</div>`
How can I read the parameter that I am passing when I load the template

Thanks.

Comment: You can add the parameter to the div and fetch it later, like `$('#Selected').load("template.html",{REQUIREDID:PARENTID}).data('val', 'requiredid')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this:

**GET:**

`$('#Selected').load("template.html?requiredid=VALUE_TO_PASS");`

**POST:**

`$('#Selected').load("template.html",{requiredid=VALUE_TO_PASS});`

Add following javascript method inside `template.html` to read the query parameters:

```
 function GetURLParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }​
```

and use it like:

```
$('#someDivId').html(GetURLParameter('requiredid'));
```

I hope, It will help.

Comment: How would you assign that value to the template?

Comment: Sorry, but there is error: not all code paths return a value  
for this function:



function GetURLParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }​

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the Value for "requiredid" from the Server and store it in a variable. You can then access it in your Callbackfunction after load is completed.

Answer (score 1):

You need it as GET parameter and access it with window.location.search as you can see here [How to get "GET" request parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript)

Or in a more better way: Place JavaScript code inside the `template.html` and use global variables from there. If the `template.html` is included in your div container, you can run inside this file JavaScript code as it would be in the main template file from where you called the `$.load` function. So, in other words: The scope is the same. Inform yourself about JavaScript scopes.

Edit: That´s a typically angular/react use case. Consider to use on of these MVVM JavaScript frameworks.