# Get Php variable in to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I know this topic is frequently asked but I've tried many ways and nothing works for me. I have a lot of checkboxes with the id generated (in Php) by a variable like this:`<input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" >`. That I want to do is call a Javascript function every time that a radiobutton (autogenerated) is clicked for that that checkbox with `id="<?php echo $id; ?>"`can be checked.

I tried with things like:

```
function check() {
    var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

I know that maybe I could do with Ajax but I don't know how.
(Up to this point is obvious that you know that the radiobutton has `onclick = "check ()"`).

If anyone can tell me what I can do is I appreciate a lot.

Comment: possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript

Comment: radiobuttons are automatically checked when clicked on, what is the scenario you are looking for?

Comment: you can run the script on document ready.

Comment: @RST is right maybe when checkbox is check it uncheck again because of your document.getElementById(id).checked = true; which toggle the check status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="radio" data-check="checkbox-<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="check(this)" />

<script>
  function check(e)
  {
    document.getElementById(e.getAttribute('data-check')).checked = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Dude, you are a teacher. Works perfectly I changed only: `data-check="<?php echo $id; ?>"` for `data-check="<?php echo $id; ?>"`.

Comment: I mean you are a MASTER. Lol. I'm really grateful. Thank you for your time and for your great help! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for dynamically generated radio and checkbox

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```