# Why can't I use globals in separate html and js files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files: index.html and lobby.html. In main.js, which I load in index.html, lobby.html is loaded using window.location.href. I have tried every way of defining globals in main.js (namespaces such as: `var Global = {}; Global.variableName = 0; ... Global.variableName = whatever;`, simply defining variables out of function scopes: `var myGlobal;` and even using `window.` to define and use globals: `window.myGlobal = 0; ... window.myGlobal = whatever;`). No matter any of these approaches, every time I try to access these "globals" in a separate script in lobby.html, it always throws an undefined error. How does this make any sense?

Comment: does lobby.html load main.js at all? is it loaded BEFORE any script that tries to use these globals?

Comment: are you sure main.js is loaded before accessing it.

Comment: Whenever you load a web page (including `window.location.href`), you're starting a new session. Anything you had in memory from a previous session is gone. Among other things, it acts as a security feature. If you want to keep some of that information, you'll either have to use cookies or pass session variables as part of your http request. e.g. `http://mypage.com/lobby.html?myGlobal=foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question, *Why can't I ...?*, is that you start a new session whenever you load a page. So, any of the Javascript variables from the previous session are gone.

The other (implied) question, *How can I keep the value of Javascript variables across sessions?* is either to [use cookies in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) (MDN) or append request variables to the end of your URL then process them when the new page loads: [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript) (SO)

Answer (score 1):

When a new page is loaded, you are essentially starting a new session as explained by others here and hence the data will be reset. For retaining some data across pages, you could use HTML5 Web storage - Session storage or Local storage as per your business needs.

**[MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)**

> The two mechanisms within Web Storage are as follows:
>
> - sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long
>   as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores).
> - localStorage does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

**[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**

> HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:
>
> ~ **window.localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date
>
> ~ **window.sessionStorage** - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

Comment: I had a lot of difficulty voting this answer up... I'm allergic to W3Schools :P (even though [there's really no reason to be any more](http://www.w3fools.com/)), but HTML5 Web Storage is a better solution in a lot of cases. There's also an [MDN Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) and HTML5Rocks links to several resources about [HTML5 Web Storage](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).

Comment: @Vince - lol, honestly I go for MDN, but for beginners (including me when I started coding) MDN is scary (just like MSDN ;) ) and W3Schools is simple enough to understand and try out the concepts :) I'm gonna update the answer with the MDN link. Thank you

Comment: @Developer I tried using sessionStorage to store a socket in socket.io (sessionStorage.socket = io();) but every time i try to call a function with the socket (sessionStorage.socket.emit(...);) the error states that "sessionStorage.socket.emit() is not a function"

Comment: You cant store an event/object in session storage; it supports string key-value pairs. May be you can serialize and store objects in session storage. But I think storing a socket is not the right way to do - there is something wrong with the approach.