# What is the best way to deal with a URL sent from an external server?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

For the (French) payment system **PayFip**, a URL is generated which opens a new window with different arguments.
Exemple :

```
https://www.payfip.gouv.fr/tpa/paiement.web?numcli=000001&exer=2018&refdet=2018EA0001&objet=&montant=11256&mel=xxx@xxx.xx&urlcl=https://www.mysite.fr/payment_return_page.php&saisie=T
```

After payment (via this new window) a URL is generated with "urlcl" and is called when this window is closed.

Example :

```
https://www.mysite.fr/payment_return_page.php?numcli=######&exer=#####&refdet=######&objet=######&montant=##########&mel=#####@###. ##&saisie=T&resultrans=#&numauto=####&dattrans=########&heurtrans=####
```

My shared server logs prove that my "payment_return_page.php" page seems to be receiving a POST. But I don't know how I can display this page.

Logically the parent page should update, right?
What is the best way to get and display the arguments (or the POST array) for this return URL?

I mainly use PHP, JS, AJAX, or JSON ... Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's your exact problem? If your server receives a `POST` request, why not handle it?

Comment: In PHP if you receive post data then it's available in the $_POST variable. What you've shown so far is request data which you would get from the $_REQUEST variable in PHP. In JavaScript see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript to get request parameters.

Comment: In my mind the parent window should update with this return url.
Am I wrong ?
But that is not what is happening. Is there a listener to set up?
I would just like to display the returned arguments.

Comment: Log the arguments into a file...

Comment: ok to log the arguments but how to trigger their display on the "payment_return_page.php" page and especially trigger the update of the parent page by the "payment_return_page.php" page?

Comment: Why not write them to the session?

Comment: Ok it's doable but I don't see how this write in session can be triggered and by what it could be. Excuse me if I seem ridiculous to you but it is surely that my logic is not ... logic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a logic like this:

- open the window and call the url of the payment system using javascript
- register a close-handler for the window
- let the payment_return_page.php write the data to the session
- wait for the close-event of the window
- reload (or relocate) the current page to a php-script that can now read the session...

Comment: I'll try your plan. Your logic seems much more logical than mine ... ; -) 
I am testing all this and I will keep you posted ... 
Thank you guys very much.