# Regular Expressions: Capture multiple groups using quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = '<12> rnbqkb-r Rnbq-b-r ';

var pat1 = new RegExp('^\\<12\\> ([rnbqkpRNBQKP-]{8}) ([rnbqkpRNBQKP-]{8})');
var pat2 = new RegExp('^\\<12\\> ([rnbqkp RNBQKP-]{8}){2}');
var pat3 = new RegExp('^\\<12\\> ([rnbqkp RNBQKP-]{8}){2}?');

document.write(str.match(pat1));
document.write('<br />');
document.write(str.match(pat2));
document.write('<br />');
document.write(str.match(pat3));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

which produces

```
<12> rnbqkb-r Rnbq-b-r,rnbqkb-r,Rnbq-b-r
<12> rnbqkb-r Rnbq-b-, Rnbq-b-
<12> rnbqkb-r Rnbq-b-, Rnbq-b-
```

as output.

Why does neither pattern `pat2` nor `pat3` capture the first group `rnbqkb-r`? I would like to capture all groups without having to repeat them explicitly as in pattern `pat1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does neither pattern pat2 nor pat3 capture the first group rnbqkb-r?

Because you have white-space at the end of each 8-character sequence that your regexes `pat2` and `pat3` do not allow.

> I would like to capture all groups without having to repeat them explicitly as in pattern pat1.

You can't.

It is not possible (in JavaScript) to capture two groups when your regex only contains one group.

Groups are defined thorugh parentheses. Your match result will contain as many groups as there are parentheses pairs in your regex (except modified parentheses like `(?:...)` which will not count towards match groups). Want two separate group matches in your match result? Define two separate groups in your regex.

If a group can match multiple times, the group's value will be whatever it matched *last*. All previous match occurrences for that group will be overridden by its last match.

Try

```
var pat1 = /^<12> ((?:[rnbqkp-]{8} ?)*)/i,
    match = str.match(pat1);

if (match) {
  match[1].split(/\s+/);  // ["rnbqkb-r", "Rnbq-b-r", ""]
}
```

Notes:

- Trim `str` beforehand if you don't want the last empty array value.
- In general, prefer regex literal notation (`/expression/`). Use `new RegExp()` only for expressions you generate from dynamic values.
- `<` and `>` are not special, you don't need to escape them.

Comment: Is this still true as of 2019? I'm just encountering this issue and can't find a more recent answer than yours.

Comment: It's still true as of 2020 even.

Answer (score 2):

Count again (8 vs 9). `pat2` and `pat3` are missing the space in between the two parts.

Update: Additionally, I don't thing it's possible what you are trying to achieve by using `match`. See [How can I match multiple occurrences with a regex in JavaScript similar to PHP's preg_match_all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps) and use `exec`.

Comment: The blank is contained in the pattern. Anyway, I tried '^\\<12\\> ([rnbqkp RNBQKP-]{9}){2}' and '^\\<12\\> ([rnbqkp RNBQKP-]{9}){2}?' which both result in <12> rnbqkb-r Rnbq-b-r ,Rnbq-b-r . Again, the first group is not captured.

Comment: See http://refiddle.com/2xh Replace 8/9 and see the difference. But that's not the root of your problem.