# Get all substrings inside a string that match a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I match multiple occurrences with a regex in JavaScript similar to PHP's preg_match_all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps)

In Javascript, is it possible to find the starting and ending indices of all substrings within a string that match a regular expression?

Function signature:

```
function getMatches(theString, theRegex){
    //return the starting and ending indices of match of theRegex inside theString
    //a 2D array should be returned
}
```

For example:

```
getMatches("cats and rats", /(c|r)ats/);
```

should return the array `[[0, 3], [9, 12]]`, which represents the starting and ending indices of "cats" and "rats" within the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `match` to find all substrings that match the regex.

```
> "cats and rats".match(/(c|r)ats/g)
> ["cats", "rats"]
```

Now you can use `indexOf` and `length` to find the start/end indices.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getMatches(theString, theRegex){
    return theString.match(theRegex).map(function(el) {
        var index = theString.indexOf(el);
        return [index, index + el.length - 1];
    });
}
getMatches("cats and rats", /(c|r)ats/g); // need to use `g`
```