# Regular Expression only returning first result found

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I match multiple occurrences with a regex in JavaScript similar to PHP’s preg_match_all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps)

I am trying to parse an xml document like this:

```
var str = data.match("<string>" + "(.*?)" + "</string>");
console.log(str);
```

I want to get all the elements between the `[string]` in an array but for some reason, it only returns the first `string` element found. Im not good with regular expressions so Im thinking this is just a small regex issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it to be global `g`

```
var str="<string>1</string><string>2</string><string>3</string>"; 
var n=str.match(/<string>(.*?)<\/string>/g);
 //1,2,3
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! I knew it was going to be something small like that. chears :)

Comment: g actually stands for global. Greedy (+ vs. ?) has a different meaning.

Comment: @Christophe, ops,  mybad

Answer (score 1):

You have to form the RegEx adding a g to it like

`/Regex/g`