# Javascript regex to bring back all symbol matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex object that brings back any matches of symbols in a string, 
take for example the following string:

```
input =    !"£$[]{}%^&*:@\~#';/.,<>\|¬`
```

then the following code:

```
input.match(regExObj,"g");
```

would return an array of matches:

```
[[,!,",£,$,%,^,&,*,:,@,~,#,',;,/,.,,,<,>,\,|,¬,`,]]
```

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
match(/[U+0021-U+0027]/g);
```

and I cannot use the following because I need to allow none ascii chars, for example Chinese characters.

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]
```

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: u can use this `[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]`

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It I cant use  [^0-9a-zA-Z\s] because the app allows for entry of noneascci chars and that would limit the input to only english alphabets.

Comment: @xerxes do you want to match symbols belonging to only ascii

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I match multiple occurrences with a regex in JavaScript similar to PHP's preg\_match\_all()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps)

Comment: I wanna match any of these symbols>    !"£$[]{}%^&*:@\~#';/.,<>\|¬`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var re = /[!"\[\]{}%^&*:@~#';/.<>\\|`]/g;
var matches = [];
var someString = "aejih!\"£$[]{}%^&*:@\~#';/.,<>\\|¬`oejtoj%";
while(match = re.exec(someString)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

Getting

```
['!','"','[',']','{','}','%','^','&','*',':','@','~','#',''',';','/','.','<','>','\','|','`','%]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
/[!"£$\[\]{}%^&*:@\\~#';\/.,<>|¬`]/g
```

?