# Javascript match all regex that returns an array of all phrases wrapped in double quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a string something like `'"this one" and "that one"'`. I want to return an array of all double quoted strings i.e. `[this one, that one]`.

So far I've tried:

```
var mystring = '"this one" and "that one"';
var m = mystring.match(/"(.*?)"/);
alert(m[1]);
```

It works fine at detecting the first occurrence of a double quoted string, but how do I get all of the phrases / words wrapped in double quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the (g)lobal modifier:

```
var mystring = '"this one" and "that one"';
var m = mystring.match(/"(.*?)"/g);
console.log(m);
```

update

```
var mystring = '"this one" and "that one"';
var m = mystring.match(/"(.*?)"/g).map(function(n){ return n.replace(/"/g,'')});
console.log(m);
```

Comment: This is close.  It is returning `["this one", "that one"]`, but I want `[this one, that one]` with no double quotes.

Comment: you can simply strip off the quotes in that case :)

Comment: I know that I didn't request this in the question, but if the string does not contain a pair of double quotes an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null` is sent to the console. I fixed this with an if-statement.