# Regex to match between 2 strings and contains another string

Tags: regex

Here is my input string

```
2014.10.30: b
l
ah bl
a
h  
2014.10.30: bfoo  
lah  
b  
l  
ah   
     2014.10.30: bart1  
     lah  
     baloon  
     l  
     ah  
2014.10.30: carb  
lah  
b  
l  
ah  
     2014.10.30: farb2  
     lah  
     baloon  
     l  
     ah  
2014.10.30: carb  
lah  
b  
l  
ah  
2014.10.30: bom  
lah  
baloob  
l  
ah  
etc
```

I would like to match the following (between the 2014 which has the word baloon inside them):

```
2014.10.30: bart1  
lah  
baloon  
l  
ah
```

and

```
2014.10.30: farb2  
lah  
baloon  
l  
ah
```

This is what I have,

```
/(2014)(.*?baloon.*)(?:2014)/gsmi
```

and this is matching from the beginning of the first occurrence of 2014. And its returning only one match with bottom to top. [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dM6bN0/2) here

Comment: Different programming languages have different flavors of regex. Most of them support "getNextMatch". For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/520845/1057429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [negative and positive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) lookahead assertion.

```
2014(?:(?!2014).)*?baloon.*?(?=\n2014)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dM6bN0/3)

**OR**

```
2014(?:(?!2014).)*?baloon(?:(?!2014).)*?(?=\n2014)
```

`(?:(?!2014).)*?` would match any character but not of `2014`. This asserts that there isn't a string `2014` present in-between the starting 2014 and  `baloon`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dM6bN0/4)