# Pre-fill Woocommerce login fields with URL variables saved in session

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using "[Pre-fill Woocommerce checkout fields with Url variables saved in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356459/pre-fill-woocommerce-checkout-fields-with-url-variables-saved-in-session/50357363#50357363)" answer code, trying to populate Woocommerce login username and password with variables saved in session.

This is my customized code in `functions.php` so far:

```
// Save user data from URL to Woocommerce session, this works fine
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_custom_data_wc_session' );
function set_custom_data_wc_session () {
    if ( isset( $_GET['sliced_client_email'] ) || isset( $_GET['tu_name'] ) ) {
        $email   = isset( $_GET['sliced_client_email'] )   ? esc_attr( $_GET['sliced_client_email'] )   : '';
        $pw = isset( $_GET['password'] ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['password'] ) : '';

        // Set the session data
        WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', array( 'email' => $email, 'password' => $pw ) );
    }
}

// Autofill checkout fields from user data saved in Woocommerce session, this is my problem
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_form' , 'prefill_login_fields' );
function prefill_login_fields ( $xxx ) {
    // Get the session data
    $data = WC()->session->get('custom_data');

    // Email
    if( isset($data['email']) && ! empty($data['email']) )
       $xxx['username']['default'] = $data['email'];

    // Password
    if( isset($data['password']) && ! empty($data['password']) )
        $xxx['password']['default'] = $data['password'];
}
```

But of course I can't find the parameters to populate. On the checkout page there is `$address_fields['billing_email']` but I can't find a similar parameter for the login page. Not sure what to put in `$xxx` and `$xxx['username']['default']` and `$xxx['password']['default']`.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Or if there is another way to simply get login fields pre-filled from URL parameters, they don't necessarily have to be stored in saved session.

Comment: I don't think that you can pre-populate the password field anyway **as it's a password field** that needs to be manually inputed. The only possible way should be to use Javascript / jQuery as those fields are hard coded in global/form-login.php template, and the linked answer code mentioned can't work on that case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found a solution using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so instead of using variables stored in session, I found [a simple jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391753/filling-out-a-form-from-the-url).

```
add_action('woocommerce_login_form','woocommerce_js_2');

function woocommerce_js_2()
{ // break out of php 
?>
<script>
// Setup a document ready to run on initial load
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var r = /[?|&](\w+)=(\w+)+/g;  //matches against a kv pair a=b
    var query = r.exec(window.location.href);  //gets the first query from the url
    while (query != null) {

            //index 0=whole match, index 1=first group(key) index 2=second group(value)
        $("input[name="+ query[1] +"]").attr("value",query[2]);

        query = r.exec(window.location.href);  //repeats to get next capture
    }

});
</script>
<?php } // break back into php
```